# The specified child already has a parent. What am I missing

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm fairly new to android studio and I'm building an app for my school project. 
I have an array list of ImageButtons that is generated and I need to assign them into rows in my TableView to make it look like a periodic table. However I keep receiving this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ros_dhhiggins.example.com.periodictable/ros_dhhiggins.example.com.periodictable.PeriodicTableScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3700)
                                                                                       at ros_dhhiggins.example.com.periodictable.PeriodicTableScreen.tableGen(PeriodicTableScreen.java:46)
                                                                                       at ros_dhhiggins.example.com.periodictable.PeriodicTableScreen.onCreate(PeriodicTableScreen.java:18)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is the Code for the Activity this is happening in:

```
package ros_dhhiggins.example.com.periodictable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
public class PeriodicTableScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_periodic_table_screen);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutTable);
    createButtons newButtons = new createButtons(this);
    tableGen(table, newButtons);
}

public void tableGen(TableLayout table, createButtons newButtons) {
    ImageButton[] imageButtons;
    imageButtons = newButtons.build();
    for(int j = 1; j <= 7; j++){
            TableRow tempRow = new TableRow(this);
        if(j==1) {
            tempRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int temp = 0; temp <= 17; temp++) {
                ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp]);
            }
        }
        else if (j==2){
                for(int temp = 18; temp <=35; temp++){
                    TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
                    rowOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        else if (j==3){
            TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
            rowOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                for(int temp = 36; temp <=53; temp++){
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        else if (j==4){
            TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
            rowOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                for(int temp = 54; temp <=71; temp++){
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        else if (j==5){
            TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
            rowOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                for(int temp = 72; temp <=89; temp++){
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        else if (j==6){

                for(int temp = 90; temp <=107; temp++){
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        else if (j==7){
                for(int temp = 108; temp <=125; temp++){
                    ImageButton tempButton = imageButtons[temp];
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);
                }
        }
        table.addView(tempRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((ViewGroup) tempRow.getParent()).removeView(tempRow);
    }
   }
}
```

If there is any other info that would be useful let me know, thanks!

Comment: Your code's kind of a jumble, but check your logic on the loop counters and array indexes in the inner `for` loops in `tableGen()`. The first row is adding `Button`s 0-17, then the second row is trying to start adding the `Button`s from 17 again - `tempRow.addView(imageButtons[temp-1]);`.

Comment: Thanks! I tottaly missed that, should have been more carefull. I had tried something out hence why the code was so messy and overlooked that. Works now.

Comment: You shouldn't have a loop if you have completely different logic for each case anyway; it defeats the purpose of a loop. And if `createButtons` is supposed to be a type, it should be spelled as such, `CreateButtons`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be because of following lines:

```
TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
            rowOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You are creating it repeatedly. You are not even using it. Try removing above lines from your loop and check. Let me know if you still face any problem.